# jquery refer to initial element selector in following selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to refer to the original selected element in the following select statement something like this:

```
$('.someclass').next('span').hide().parent().append('<input class="textbox" name="'+$(this).attr("name")+'-x'+'"/>');
```

Where $(this) was the original $('.someclass') element.

I am trying to get attributes from the inital element to apply to another element in the statement.

## edit

Since the initial element is selected by class, there are multiple elements with the same classname.

This is the source html:

```
<div>
<input class="someclass" name="somename">
<span></span>
```

I want to hide the input, and add a new input using the original input's name with a prefix.

Comment: should work - did you try it?

Comment: yes I tried it, results in undefined even though the original element has it's name attribute set.

Comment: @MarcB `end` wouldn't work in this case. It's used to reset the chain back to the initial selector, not change the context of `this`.

Answer (score 2):

Your title asks something different to your question.

`.end()` traverses to the initial element, but you want to use that element to affect another.

```
$('.someclass').each(function(){
    $(this).next('span').hide().append('<input class="textbox" name="'+$(this).attr("name")+'-x'+'"/>');
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0ub2ht5s/

or if you prefer to create the element than the HTML

```
$('.someclass').each(function(){
    $input = $('<input>', {
        name: $(this).attr("name")+'-x',
    }).addClass('textbox');
    $(this).next('span').append($input);
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0ub2ht5s/2/

I removed `.hide()` from the fiddle otherwise you'd see nothing.

You could do it with the syntax you provided by giving append a function, but you'd be traversing unnecessarily, so **don't do the following**, it's here as an example:

```
$('.someclass').each(function(){
    $(this).next('span').append(function(){
        return '<input class="textbox" name="'+$(this).prev().attr("name")+'-x'+'"/>'
    });
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0ub2ht5s/1/

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible with the syntax you have used. You need to store the original element in a variable:

```
var $el = $('.someclass');
$el.next('span').hide().parent().append('<input class="textbox" name="' + $el.attr("name") + '-x"/>');
```

Comment: What if there is multiple `.someclass`?

Comment: In that case an `each()` call as in @Popnoodles answer would be the best solution, however OP has given no indication of his HTML structure.

Comment: It not being possible is not true. You can throw a function into `append()` but in this case the code would be untidy.

Comment: @Popnoodles You can give `append` a function, but even in there `this` would reference the element in `parent()`, not `$('.someclass')`.

Comment: Not when you traverse (unnecessarily)

Comment: You mean put the `append` on the initial selector and do the traversal within the `append` function? If so, yes that would work.